# Finding the max within a a group in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following problem (SQL code written in Oracle SQL)

Input

```
Country  City     Time (datatype=text)
AB       XY       10:00
AB       XY       12:00
AB       XY       15:00
CD       GY       10:30
CD       GY       17:00
DE       ED       11:00
DE       ED       14:00
```

The output should look like this below selecting only the countries and cities with the maximum time

```
Country  City     Time
AB       XY       15:00
CD       GY       17:00
DE       ED       14:00
```

For now my code is like this. I need to do a subquery to take into account the max over partition oracle sql code

```
SELECT distinct
country,
city,
time
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

Comment: That's just a MAX(Time) GROUP BY Country, City

Comment: What's the data type of your `Time` column?

Comment: the issue is I ma already using a group inside the query, so i am looking for a subquery that I am finding difficult to write

Answer (score 1):

Isn't what you want just

```
MPOWEL01> select country, city, max(timec) from t1
  2  group by country, city
  3  /

CO CI MAX(T
-- -- -----
AB XY 15:00
CD GY 17:00
DE ED 14:00

3 rows selected.
```

I do not think you should use character (text) for a TIME value.  Use a DATE or TIMESTAMP datatype and just use a constant for the day, month, year or extract the time from actual date values via TO_CHAR or EXTRACT.